# How to install applet with default select

Tags: javacard

I want to install an applet in the java card, but I don't want to select it when inserted in card reader.

I want to send  A404000A 504159464C4558503553 as my first command. I checked and found that install with -d in JCOP can solve my purpose, but where I set it?

Currently, my JCOP tool sending install command looks like:

```
install -i 504159464c4558503553 -q C9#() a0a1a2a3a4a5 a0a1a2a3a4a5a6
```

but i want jcop send -d too. Perhaps it will solve my purpose.

how can I set `-d` in JCOP?

Comment: I used Gpshell here and with -priv 4 option I found no need to send select applet command but expecting 0x6099 because i code it like this. In debug code it return it but when work on real card it gives 0x9000. Strange but happening in my case.

Comment: Do you have the correct card life cycle state? This privilege works in OP_SECURED. In OP_READY and OP_INITIALIZED the ISD is the default selected application.

Answer (score 1):

`-d` is equal to `--default` and will mark the applet as default selected. This means that the applet is selected as soon as the card is put into the reader and ATR/ATS is issued. Unfortunatly your question is not clearly stated if this behaviour is desired or not. Usage for JCOP Shell install command is:

> install [-e|--delegation][-l|--cm-lock][-t|--terminate][-d|--default][-p|--pin-change][-s|--security-domain][-b|--sd-dap][-m|--mandated-dap][-q|--install-param params][-i|--instance-aid AID][-o|--install-only] pkgAID appAID

The order of optional arguments is not evaluated, so for example use:

```
install -i 504159464c4558503553 -d -q C9#() a0a1a2a3a4a5 a0a1a2a3a4a5a6
```

Comment: I tried this when i send command manually one by one  and it work good, but how I can set this -d in JCOP so all the time when debug or run my code, it send -d with install along with other command like init-update , ext-auth and etc

Comment: For installation on real cards i use jcsh scripts where all commands are stored and i just call the shellscript name in the JCOP shell. For debugging oben the debug configuration... window and on the applet tab you go on the edit button and check the default select option

Comment: you mean you put the command on another file and call it from JCOP. How can i do the same? I did not find any option where i can set the path of script want to execute on run time.

Comment: create a new file, for example installthis.jcsh, put all the commands in it, call /set path <yourpath> and then installthis in the JCOP shell. i usually put the /set path command as a comment in the first line of the shell script so you can copy paste when you restart eclipse. I don't have the JCOP tools on this computer so i cannot explain in detail where the edit button is located. Did you create a new Debug configuration under Javacard category in the Debug configurations... menu?

Comment: Debug Configurations...  -> select <yourJCconfiguration>  ->  package upload tab  ->  select your Applet -> edit button is available on the right

Comment: The command is  '/set-var path "yourpath"'. In Eclipse, you can put this command in the Run Configuration > Shell Initialization > Shell Commands section so that it will be automatically defined with each run.